# Can't scroll in tableView while searching in UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

if i am searching something in the searchbar (it is embedded in the navigationBar) I can't scroll in the tableview. If i tap on the tableview while searching the search ends and i can tap the cells, but i want to be able to scroll while searching and tap cells normally.

This is how i add the searchController:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add this:

```swift
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
```

Comment: iOS SDK is becoming a hodgepodge. I think on iOS 15 you don't need to set this to false; but on 14 you do.